# What is the sufficient condition for the value of integrable function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ to go to $0$ when $|x|\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the sufficient condition for the value of integrable function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ to go to $0$ when $|x|\rightarrow \infty$?

Case 1: $f $ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Case 2: $f$ is ddifferentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f'|<\infty$.

I think the  case 1 is enough to prove $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$, because $f$ is differentiable everywhere, so f is at least continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. By the integral of $f$ we can get $\lim\sup_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}|f(x)|=0$, otherwise we can find a counterexample. Is that correct?

Then I am thinking that if we change the condition ''$f$ is differentiable'' to be ''$f$ is differentiable almost everywhere'', then what hanppens?

Comment: It's "differentiable" in English, and I think you're right. As to a.s., this should't matter as the integral over a null set won't matter.

Comment: You mean $f$ is differentiable a.e so that $f$ is continuous a.e, we can eliminate a null set.

Comment: But if the null set has infinite many points that tend to $\infty$ and the value of $f$ on these points are always better than $1$, we can't get $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: They would be points of discontinuity though on a null set, with the points in the complement of that null set well behaved. And my understanding of your question is that the function is integrable, so the case you describe should not be possible. However, a strict proof should be necessary, I agree.

Comment: How about $f(x)=1/q$ if $x=p/q \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)=0,$ if $x$ is irrational?

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb{Q}$. And isn't that a counter to *necessary*, and you are looking for *sufficient*?

Comment: Differentiability isn't enough. On any interval $[a,b]$, you can construct a differentiable function $f$ with $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$ and $f((a+b)/2)=1$. (The area under the graph over $[a,b]$ can be made as small as you like by selecting $a$ and $b$ appropriately.)

Comment: @gnometorule, yes, it should be $\mathbb{Q}$, I put this example just want to say the case I describe above can be possible, f is integrable but there are also many infinite points st the value can be bigger than one.

Comment: @David Mitra, that is the problem, your example is partially the same as  what I posted. Actually, in your example, say $[n,n+1], f(n)=f(n+1)=0, f((n+1)/2)=1, \int_n^{n+1} |f|=1/n^2 $, then $f$ if continuous, differentiable and integrable but do not have a limit.

Comment: Here is some related article:http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2013/vol14-n1/paper1/v14n1-1pd.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A] Consider a smooth function, null outside $[0,1]$. Now consider 
$$
g(x) = \sum f(n^2(x-n))
$$

Then $\limsup g = \sup f$ and as $\sum n^{-2}<\infty$, $\int|g|<\infty$.

B] Consider a sequence $x_n$ increasing to $\infty$.
Then the sequence $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence:
$$|f(x_{n+p}) - f(x_n)| =\left| \int_{x_{n}}^{x_{n+p}}f'\right|
\le \int_{x_{n}}^{\infty}|f'|  = \epsilon_n \to 0
$$hence the sequence converge. The only possible limit is $0$.

edit: added B.

Comment: Yes, you are right, now I know that the case 1 is not a sufficient condition to prove $f$ has a limit at infinity.  By the continuity of integral, I think case 2 will work, $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\leq\int_x^{x+h} |f'| <\epsilon $ when $h<\delta$, so $f$ is Cauchy continuous at $x=\infty$, so $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists, then it must be zero.

Comment: Added the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R).$ Also assume that, its [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), $\hat{f}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R).$ Then $f$ is continuous and vanishing at infinity.(By inversion formula, and Reimann Lebesgue lemma)

Comment: Can you see more clearly? Now I know that continuity and differetiability can not guarantee $f$ has a limit at $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition you want is uniform continuity. With merely continuity, you can imagine a continuous function which consists of countably many triangles centered at $2,3,\dots$ of height $1$ and width $1/4,1/9,\dots,1/n^2,\dots$. You can even imagine them being height $n$ and width $1/8,1/27,\dots,1/n^3,\dots$, if you want the function to be unbounded. It's also not a big deal to smooth out this example if you want to assume a certain amount of differentiability.

With uniform continuity, if there is any $\varepsilon$ so that arbitrarily large $x$ satisfy $|f(x)| \geq \varepsilon$, then each such $x$ supplies an interval of a *fixed* width $\delta$ in which $|f(z)| \geq \varepsilon/2$, and so you wind up with countably many intervals which each contribute $\varepsilon \delta/2$ to the integral, which makes $f \notin L^1$.